# How to script ranger to copy a file to another directory via python

Tags: python, ranger

`ranger` is a command line file manager that can be extended with python. The `commands.py` file contains examples of the built in commands:

https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/config/commands.py

I can see how to delete files via `self.fm.delete()` and I have explored the `fm.py` file and don't see a function that looks to be exposed that would allow me to copy files in a straightforward way (but I'm not a python dev so maybe I don't understand it):

https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/core/fm.py

I just want a function that will copy the `current selection` to a `~/.directory/`.

I know I could do this with a key mapping, but I want to do it in python so that I can extend it, but I can't get past this one basic step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp... this is what I ended up with, but I'm not sure if there is a better way:

```
class cpto(Command):                                   
    """:cpto                                           

    copies the file to a special directory                      
    """                                                 
    def execute(self):                                               
        self.fm.execute_console("shell cp %s ~/.special_directory &")
```

I was able to explore the `fm` object more in-depth by cloning the ranger repo, `cd`ing into it, and running `pydoc.ranger.core.actions`

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same function by creating a mapping in your `rc.conf` file as follows:

```
map cto shell -f cp %s ~/.special_directory/
```

Then, you will select the files you need to copy, and press `cto`.

Comment: Except for the part where the OP says: “I know I could do this with a key mapping, but I want to do it in python”